# Windows phone: Combine images and make a video file

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, video

I have a set of Images and i want to make a video with them.
I made a R&D over that and i found a lots of way like, [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). but there is nothing worked with windows phone 7.

My concept is just **combine the set of images and prepare a video** with any video format that you tube supports. and then i have to share this video on you tube.
I completed the share Functionality. but, i have a confusion in this generating video functionality.

Please suggest me any possible solution with windows phone 7. Waiting for your valuable feedback.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are out of luck, this is not possible

Comment: making images from a video is certainly a possibility, But the reverse isn't possible.